# Regular expression pattern to remove parentheses (and any parentheses inside)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

The input is a Wikipedia page's first paragraph. I want to remove anything between parentheses and the parentheses themselves.

However, at times (often), the HTML content inside parentheses itself contains one or several parentheses, generally in the `href=""` of a link.

Take the following:

```
<p>
    The <b>Sarcopterygii</b> or <b>lobe-finned fish</b> (from Greek σαρξ <i>sarx</i>, flesh, and πτερυξ <i>pteryx</i>, fin) – sometimes considered synonymous with <b>Crossopterygii</b> ("fringe-finned fish", from Greek κροσσός <i>krossos</i>, fringe) – constitute a <a href="/wiki/Clade" title="Clade">clade</a> (traditionally a <a href="/wiki/Class_(biology)" title="Class (biology)">class</a> or subclass) of the <a href="/wiki/Osteichthyes" title="Osteichthyes">bony fish</a>, though a strict <a href="/wiki/Cladistic" class="mw-redirect" title="Cladistic">cladistic</a> view includes the terrestrial <a href="/wiki/Vertebrate" title="Vertebrate">vertebrates</a>.
</p>
```

I want the end-result to be:

```
<p>
    The <b>Sarcopterygii</b> or <b>lobe-finned fish</b> – sometimes considered synonymous with <b>Crossopterygii</b> – constitute a <a href="/wiki/Clade" title="Clade">clade</a> of the <a href="/wiki/Osteichthyes" title="Osteichthyes">bony fish</a>, though a strict <a href="/wiki/Cladistic" class="mw-redirect" title="Cladistic">cladistic</a> view includes the terrestrial <a href="/wiki/Vertebrate" title="Vertebrate">vertebrates</a>.
</p>
```

But when I use the below `preg_replace` pattern it doesn't work, becomes it gets confused by the parentheses within parentheses.

```
public function removeParentheses( $content ) {

    $pattern = '@\(.*?\)@';
    $content = preg_replace( $pattern, '', $content );
    $content = str_replace( ' .', '.', $content );
    $content = str_replace( '  ', ' ', $content );
    return $content;
}
```

Secondly, how can I leave the parentheses inside links' `href=""` and `title=""`? These, if not within a text parentheses are important.

Comment: regular expressions cant handle recursion. If you have some recursive patterns (parens inside parens..) you need more logic - i.e. write an parser

Comment: Do not parse HTML with regex. As @Philipp mentioned, it cannot do this effectively (sure you can hack together a version that works, but I guarantee you it can be broken by some obscure thing in HTML). Use an XML parser like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php)

Comment: you may want to reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php for a list of tools to use if trying to parse html with php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all the links with a placeholder, *then* remove all parentheses, and at the end replace the placeholders back to their original values.

This is accomplished with [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), passing a occurrences counter and a replacements array to keep track of the links, then using your own `removeParentheses()` to get rid of the parentheses, and finally using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to get your links back:

```
<?php
$string = '<p>
The <b>Sarcopterygii</b> or <b>lobe-finned fish</b> (from Greek σαρξ <i>sarx</i>, flesh, and πτερυξ <i>pteryx</i>, fin) – sometimes considered synonymous with <b>Crossopterygii</b> ("fringe-finned fish", from Greek κροσσός <i>krossos</i>, fringe) – constitute a <a href="/wiki/Clade" title="Clade">clade</a> (traditionally a <a href="/wiki/Class_(biology)" title="Class (biology)">class</a> or subclass) of the <a href="/wiki/Osteichthyes" title="Osteichthyes">bony fish</a>, though a strict <a href="/wiki/Cladistic" class="mw-redirect" title="Cladistic">cladistic</a> view includes the terrestrial <a href="/wiki/Vertebrate" title="Vertebrate">vertebrates</a>.
</p>';
$occurrences = 0;
$replacements = [];
$replacedString = preg_replace_callback("/<a .*?>.*?<\/a>/i", function($el) use (&$occurrences, &$replacements) {
    $replacements["|||".$occurrences] = $el[0]; // the ||| are just to avoid unwanted matches
    return "|||".$occurrences++;
}, $string);
function removeParentheses( $content ) {
    $pattern = '@\(.*?\)@';
    $content = preg_replace( $pattern, '', $content );
    $content = str_replace( ' .', '.', $content );
    $content = str_replace( '  ', ' ', $content );
    return $content;
}
$replacedString = removeParentheses($replacedString);
$replacedString = str_replace(array_keys($replacements), array_values($replacements), $replacedString); // get your links back
echo $replacedString;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/qubvh)

**Result**

```
<p>
The <b>Sarcopterygii</b> or <b>lobe-finned fish</b> – sometimes considered synonymous with <b>Crossopterygii</b> – constitute a <a href="/wiki/Clade" title="Clade">clade</a> of the <a href="/wiki/Osteichthyes" title="Osteichthyes">bony fish</a>, though a strict <a href="/wiki/Cladistic" class="mw-redirect" title="Cladistic">cladistic</a> view includes the terrestrial <a href="/wiki/Vertebrate" title="Vertebrate">vertebrates</a>.
</p>
```

This is however a bit brittle in my opinion. As others told you in the comments, you [shouldn't parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). A *lot* can change and you can get unexpected results. This might get you in the right direction though.

*edit* regarding the parentheses within parentheses, you can use a recursive pattern. Take a look at [this great answer by Bart Kiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12763017/8469069):

```
function removeParentheses( $content ) {
    $pattern = '@\(([^()]|(?R))*\)@';
    $content = preg_replace( $pattern, '', $content );
    $content = str_replace( ' .', '.', $content );
    $content = str_replace( '  ', ' ', $content );
    return $content;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/NgrU0)

Comment: This does not handle the problem of brackets within brackets as the user requested. Just the problem of the brackets in links.
https://3v4l.org/VDebj

Comment: @Jeff Thanks. It does now.