# PCRE conditional subpatterns: (R) as the condition

Tags: php, regex, pcre

This is from the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php) regarding PCRE conditional subpatterns:

> The two possible forms of conditional subpattern are:
>   `(?(condition)yes-pattern)`
>   `(?(condition)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`

That's OK as long as the condition is a digit or an assertion. But I don't quite understand the following

> If the condition is the string (R), it is satisfied  if a recursive
>   call to the pattern or subpattern has been made.  At "top level", the
>   condition is false. (...) If the condition is not a sequence of digits
>   or (R), it must be an assertion.

I would be grateful if someone could explain **on an example** what (R) is in conditional subpattern and how to use it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840988/the-recognizing-power-of-modern-regexes <-- there are quite thorough explanations there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an additional and clearer answer…

2 days ago I was writing a pattern to match an IPv4 address and I found myself using the recursion in condition so I thought I should share (because it makes more sense than imaginative examples).

```
~
(?:(?:f|ht)tps?://)?            # possibly a protocol
(
    (?(R)\.)                    # if it\'s a recursion, require a dot
    (?:                         # this part basically looks for 0-255
        2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5])
        | 1\d\d
        | \d\d?
    )
)(?1){3}                        # go into recursion 3 times
                                # for clarity I\'m not including the remaining part
~xi
```

Comment: Thanks! Although the same can be easily achieved without conditionals. You just need to remove `(?(R)\.)` and replace `(?1){3}` with `(?:\.(?1)){3}`

Comment: You could have a nested conditional subpattern in the recursion, though.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Your example is much closer to the real world than the previous ones.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand (from the recursion as the condition in a subpattern) here's a very basic example.

```
$str = 'ds1aadfg346fgf gd4th9u6eth0';
preg_match_all('~(?(R).(?(?=[^\d])(?R))|\d(?R)?)~'
/*
(?                          # [begin outer cond.subpat.]
    (R)                     # if this is a recursion               ------> IF
    .                       # match the first char
    (?                      # [begin inner cond.subpat.]
        (?=[^\d])           # if the next char is not a digit
            (?R)            # reenter recursion
    )                       # [end inner cond.subpat.]
    |                       # otherwise                             -----> ELSE
    \d(?R)?                 # match a digit and enter recursion (note the ?)
)                           # [end outer cond.subpat.]
*/
,$str,$m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

And the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1aadfg
    [1] => 34
    [2] => 6fgf gd
    [3] => 4th
    [4] => 9u
    [5] => 6eth
    [6] => 0
)
```

I know this is a silly example but I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The (R) stands for recursion. Here is a good example of using it.

[Recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php#102748)

Not sure I have ever seen `(?R)` used as the **condition**, or even a situation where that would be usable, or at least not in my understanding. but you learn new stuff every day in programming.

It could be used very easily as the **true or false** statement.

as per this:

```
< (?: (?(R) \d++  | [^<>]*+) | (?R)) * >
```

Where as `(?R)` is used in the false statement.
Which matches text in angle brackets, allowing for arbitrary nesting. Only digits are allowed in nested brackets (that is, when recursing), whereas any characters are permitted at the outer level.

I know this is not the answer you are looking for.... You have now sent me on a quest to research this.

Comment: I know what (R) is. Could you please explain how can I use it in conditional subpatterns (that was the original question)?

Comment: Here is a great example explained perfectly: [Recursive R](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8442349/1880925)

Comment: This is not what I'm lookung for. I'm trying to clarify for myself how to use recursion as a condition - (?(R)true|false).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is with `\d++` and `[^<>]*+`?

Comment: @inhan [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

Comment: @Wiseguy Thank you. It amazes me to discover something new each day about Regex rules. I'll sure read that.

Comment: Thanks! Although I can't see any practical use for this regex it makes some sense - something like "match a tag containing any characters with any number of nested tags containing only digits".